# Filtering in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, ecmascript-5

I have a list of 10 items from which I have to take out 1 item. i.e if both ‘Item1’ and ‘item2’ exists in myItems then I should take out ‘item2’ from ‘myItems’. Is there a simpler and better way of doing it ***(without arrow functions)*** compared to what I have below.

```
 function getFilteredItems(myItems) {
           var items = ['item1', 'item2'];             

           var filteredItems = myItems.filter(function (myItem) {
               return items.indexOf(myItem.name) !== -1;
           });

           if (filteredItems && filteredItems.length > 1) {

               myItems = myItems.filter(function (myItem) {
                   return 'item2' !== myItem.name;
               });
           }

           return myItems;
       }
```

Comment: My answer is the only one with no arrow functions; anyone can understand it.

Comment: Agree. But I want to avoid using includes as 'Item1' is not always same. This is the reason I declared items as array and not as 2 variables.

Comment: Any specific reason you are avoiding arrow functions? It's pretty easy to convert arrow functions to non-arrow functions. i updated my answer.

Comment: @JacobThomas - I cannot use ES6. you answer takes out both item1 and item2 from myItems. I want to take out item2 only when myItems has both item1 and item2.

Comment: @San you're right, that was my misunderstanding. I updated my answer, but honestly your function would work fine. I'm just enjoying challenging myself a little.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i would do.
I prefer this because you can easily add objects to `items` and have them filter out, or have it entirely dynamic

```
function getFilteredItems(myItems) {
    var items = [{name:'item1'}, {name:'item2'}];
    if( myItems.reduce((c, item) => c += items.map(obj => obj.name).includes(item.name) , 0) == 2 ) { items.shift(); };
    return myItems.filter(item => !items.map(obj => obj.name).includes(item.name) )
}
```

if `items` isnt full of objects

```
function getFilteredItems(myItems) {
    var items = ['item1', 'item2'];
    if( myItems.reduce((c, item) => c += items.includes(item.name) , 0) == 2 ) { items.shift(); };
    return myItems.filter(item => !items.includes(item.name) )
}
```

EDIT: no arrow functions

```
// items is objects
function getFilteredItems(myItems) {
    var items = [{name:'item1'}, {name:'item2'}];
    if( myItems.reduce(function(c, item) { return c += items.map( function(obj) { return obj.name}).includes(item.name)} , 0) == 2 ) { items.shift(); };
    return myItems.filter( function(item) { return !items.map( function(obj) {return obj.name}).includes(item.name)} )
}


// items is strings
function getFilteredItems(myItems) {
    var items = ['item1', 'item2'];
    if( myItems.reduce(function(c, item){ return c += items.includes(item.name) } , 0) == 2 ) { items.shift(); };
    return myItems.filter( function(item) { return !items.includes(item.name)} )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeDups(items) {
  var newItems = [];

  items.forEach(function(item) { 
    if (!newItems.includes(item)) { 
      return newItems.push(item) 
    } 
  });

  return newItems;
}
```

Now call removeDups with your array of items

```
var items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'];
removeDups(items); // ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

This assumes that your list does not have objects. If your list has objects, replace the condition in if to match your objects.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
if(myItems.includes("item1") && myItems.includes("item2")){
  myItems.splice(myItems.indexOf("item2"),1);
}
```

```js
var myItems = ["item1","item2","item3","item4","item5","item6"];
console.log(myItems);
function deleteItem(){
  if(myItems.includes(document.getElementById("itemA").value) && myItems.includes(document.getElementById("itemB").value)){
    myItems.splice(myItems.indexOf(document.getElementById("itemB").value),1);
  }
  console.log(myItems);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="itemA">If this...<br>
<input type="text" id="itemB">and this... delete this<br>
<button onclick="deleteItem();">Delete!</button>
```

Comment: i have a feeling `items` wont be a standard size in reality

Comment: @JacobThomas What do you mean? The `1` in the `splice` is how many to delete.

Comment: My array is array of objects. I kept it simpler for sake of my post. Also doing .includes twice internally does the looping twice.

Comment: i mean, `myItems.includes("item1") && myItems.includes("item2")` is hardcoded, one condition per value. that isnt ideal, especially if that is dynamic

Comment: This code should work regardless of how long `myItems` is or what `"item1"` and `"item2"` are.

Comment: @JacobThomas The question asks how to delete item2 if both item1 and item2 are present. This code does precisely that and no more.

Comment: I think it should work no matter how long `myItems` is. I'm going to edit the answer into a Stack Snippet.

Comment: It looks like you *oversimplified* the question. The property name (`name`) of an object is unique so it is enough to `.filter(item => item.name === 'item1')`

Answer (score -1):

myitems.filter( item => !items.includes(item))

Comment: `myItems` seems to be an array of objects with a name property, `'item2' !== myItem.name`

Comment: myitems.filter( item => !items.includes(item.name))